# C printf format strings

Tags: c, printf

In C language, out of the following program is %5%% ,
but I don't know how ?

```
 printf("%6%5%%%78%");
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but that doesn't look like a valid format string for `printf`... and, as for C99 §7.19.6.1 ¶9, "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.".

Comment: @AxelIsouard He probably meant 'I don't know why'.

Comment: First, try to run it and then add a comment here.

Comment: Please tell us the output you're expecting.

Comment: output as mentioned above is %5%%.

Comment: it is not what I am Expecting, it is the output generated on DEv compiler

Comment: @  Matteo Italia: yaah, I know that given string doesn't seem to be a valid format string, but it is. And that is what I am asking for.

Comment: @AsdAsd: The string is **not** a valid format string. The C standard **requires** that a “%” conversion specifier appear as “%%”, not “%6%”, per C 1999 7.19.6.1 8.

Answer (score 6):

This is undefined behavior and is compiler/platform specific. Printf functions with erroneous arguments will start ripping variables from the stack and then anything can happen.

That is why the compiler will normally complain about this

```
source.c:5:5: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat]
source.c:5:5: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat]
source.c:5:5: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat]
source.c:5:5: warning: spurious trailing '%' in format [-Wformat]
```

Comment: But, I am running this statement on Dev compiler and it is succesfully running. And I got this question in an examination, and they also have given the question after testing only.

Comment: @AsdAsd: There's no contradiction between "anything could happen and the program is ill-formed" and "it compiles". Think about that, as long as it takes. This is a *really* important point.

Comment: @Asd: just because something *appears* to run OK, it doesn't mean that it is correct. Also you should probably consider changing to a course at a better school if you're getting this kind of thing as an exam question.

Comment: Its a Company's placement paper question

Comment: Tell them the behavior is undefined and why... That will be what they are expecting.

Comment: I am sure, It has some reason and you don't know that is different. so, stop mentioning it here. I will explore it on my own.

Comment: I asked for the help and not for the comments on question.

Comment: @AsdAsd Take a look at details i have posted. They help you understand what happens and why

Comment: @Asd: you really don't want to work for that company if this is the kind of nonsensical interview question that they set.

Answer (score 3):

Printf format string should be followed by equal number of arguments which is clearly not done here.

the possible parameters to printf format string are:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

where specifier is *s* for *string*, *c* for *char* etc. Others are optional.

flags are one of +,-,0 etc. for left or right justification, none of which are passed in the question.

precision is prefixed with a ., so it is out in case of this example.

Let's look at

```
printf("%6%5%%%78%");
```

- Now the first argument after % is taken as width of field i.e. 6 and
  hence is not printed. However, it expects a specifier latter instead
  of which it finds another %. Standard says % followed by % prints it
  to stdout. Hence you see % printed first. Now because effect of % is
  lost, so 5 is treated and printed as a normal number.
- Then we see %% which would print a single %. Next is again a single
  %, followed by 78, which is expected as width and hence not printed.
  However, latter another % negates the effect of 78 and prints a
  single %.

To validate above assessment here is a test string

```
printf("%6%4%3%2");
```

which prints %4%2 in compliance with above.

for detailed reference
[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 0):

What likely happened here is:

- The printf implementation sees “%6”, which can be the start of a valid conversion specification, such as “%6d”.
- Then it sees “%”, and this can no longer be a valid conversion specification. At this point the string is not in conformance with the C standard (e.g., C 1999 7.19.6.1 8 says “The complete conversion specification shall be %%.”), and the implementation may do anything. This particular implementation appears to disregard the “6” and act as if the conversion specification were “%%” instead of “%6%”. Thus, it writes a “%” to standard output.
- Then the printf implementation sees “5”, so it writes “5”.
- Then it sees “%%”, which is a valid conversion specification that causes “%” to be written.
- Then it sees “%78%”. As with “%6%”, the “%78” could start a valid specification, but the second “%” is wrong. Once again, the implementation disregards the “78” and writes “%”.

The behavior will vary in other C implementations. The program is ill-formed; it does not conform to the C standard, and its behavior is not specified by the C standard.